# List view shows only those items which are shared with the user

Tags: 2013, document-library, permissions, list-view, share

I have a **document library** and it has some folders. Everyone can view all the folders. Folders are shared with some users giving edit permission. I want to create two **list view** of this library.

1. Everyone can show all the folders in this view
2. Only show the folders that the user has edit permission

The first one is easy to create by giving everyone **view only** permission to the library.

How to create the second list view? Is the permission I gave for list view 1 drive me in wrong way?